# Trouble posting un-checked checkbox value in django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, web

I am finding trouble in posting the state of a checkbox in a Django form (**Django v1.2**).

Here's the field in my model:

`subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Subscribe")`

In the relevant template file:

`{{ form.subscribe }}`

This renders the checkbox as un-checked initially. But when I post the form (without touching anything else), django sends `u'subscribe': [u'on']` in `request.POST`. That is, the response always contains `u'subscribe': [u'on']` irrespective of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

When the checkbox is not checked, the `<input>` tag in template is rendered as
`<input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" id="id_subscribe" />`

And, when the checkbox is checked, it is rendered as
`<input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" id="id_subscribe" checked="checked" />`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What do you get after form validation? Does the value in form.cleaned_data['subscribe'] change depending on the checkbox state? Can you post the ModelForm declaration?

Comment: The issue might be in your views, how are you collecting your data?

Comment: @cfedermann The form is validating. I am printing `request.POST` after form validation. It prints `u'subscribe': [u'on']`. The ModelForm doesn't have anything special. Some clean functions for fields other than `subscribe`. I am also applying some styles to widgets in `__init__`. That's all.  
@zallarak I collect data from `request.POST` and save a form like this: `SubscriberForm(request.POST, instance=user).save()`

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is what posts the value as 'on'.  This is normal behavior for checkbox inputs without value="blah" attribute set.  If it is always posting as 'on' even when the checkbox isn't checked then perhaps there is something on the browser side that is setting this.